# How to run second function after the first has ended in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addItemToCart (id_1, id_2, id_3, id_etc) {
  jQuery.ajax({

  });
}

function clearCart()
{
  jQuery.ajax({
  });
}

function buyButton()
{ 
    clearCart();
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        redirect to cart;
        addItemToCart(283746 , 1, 1, "Months", "1294");
    }, 500);
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that instead of using a setTimeout it waits until the clearCart() has finished loading through ajax and then it runs the functions inside the setTimeout and I can't seem to figure this out.. I tried doing a callback but I'd say that it isn't correct..

```
function FirstFunction(callBack)
{
    clearCart();

    if (callback)
    {
        callback();
    }       
}
function SecondFunction()
{
    buyButton();
}

FirstFunction(SecondFunction);
```

Comment: Run it in the .done handler

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run some code when an Ajax response has arrived, put it in the `done` or `success` handler function. That is what those functions are for.

Don't guess how long the request is going to take.

Comment: you can do it by adding `.done(function(data){ /* your function*/ })` after your ajax call.

Comment: @ABr, I tried the following but even with the done or the success it did not work, http://pastebin.com/7yMahd0L I also tried including it in the ajax success but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Need to use `done` or `success` callback to avoid any random waiting time. like below:

```
function clearCart()
{
  return jQuery.ajax({
  });
}

function buyButton()
{ 
    clearCart().done(function () {
        addItemToCart(283746 , 1, 1, "Months", "1294");
    });
}
```

Comment: @iBrazilian2 In `clearCart()`, you need to `return` the `jQuery.ajax()`.